# Retrieve html from element into a variable

Tags: jquery

I want to retrieve the html within an element and save it into a variable that I'll use for post.

Here's an example of the html:

```
<article id="editable2">
<p>blablabla</p>
</article>
```

This is the jquery I used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#save").click(function(){

      $('#editable2').prop('outerHTML');
      alert( $(this).data("outerHTML") );

    });

});
```

However the popup box keeps on saying *undefined*.

Thanks!

Comment: You are never adding the key `outerHTML` to the data store anywhere. You might want to read up on what `.data` does: http://api.jquery.com/data/. Maybe you intended to write `alert($('#editable2').prop('outerHTML'))`?

Comment: I would use Firebug or Chrome dev tools to debug the jQuery.  Test to see what your variables contain.  Put a break point on your alert and then, for instance, see what $(this) is returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to assign the content of a  to a variable you could do something like the following.

HTML

```
<article id="editable2">
  <p>content</p>
</article>

<a href="#" id="save">click</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#save").click(function(){
    var popup = $('#editable2').prop("outerHTML");
    alert( popup );
  });

});
```

Here's a working example: http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/jiDmx

If you're trying to get just the contents of the #editable2 div (which is my guess), then just do:

```
var popup = $('#editable2').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `alert( $('#editable2').html());`

Comment: Thanks, but then there is no variable to use for post, is there? How would that work?

Comment: Well I wanted to use ajax to save the variable into a mysql table.